# VS Code can't format code in <script> tags in .vue files (extensions: Vetur, Prettier)

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, prettier, vetur, prettier-vscode

I've just started using the Vetur VS Code extension for formatting .vue files. Everything seemed to work fine (syntax highlight, EMMET, etc.), but it just doesn't want to format the JavaScript code in  tags. "Prettier" can't format it either. I tried to tweak my settings, tried disabling Prettier and Vetur respectively, but nothing seems to work. Code formatting is fine in  and , though.

Now the project I'm going to be working on doesn't have any build steps, it uses Single File Component loader, so ESLint and Prettier in my build tooling is out of the picture. Plus, I'd rather have these tools in my IDE/Editor.

Where could the problem be? It looks like some sort of bug to me, I just don't know in which component: VS Code? Prettier? Vetur?

Thank you!

Comment: check in Problems and Output tab's for errors, if the html in the template is invalid it may not get to the script part, by invalid I mean it could even be nested p tags, it would help if you added your code here.

Comment: Thanks. This is what Prettier printed out (seems okay to me), nothing else is showing any errors:
{
  "ignored": false,
  "inferredParser": "vue"
}
["INFO" - 11:27:55 AM] No local configuration (i.e. .prettierrc or .editorconfig) detected, falling back to VS Code configuration
["INFO" - 11:27:55 AM] Prettier Options:
{
 ...
}
["INFO" - 11:27:55 AM] Formatting completed in 61.006472ms.

Comment: Thanks Lawrence, I checked the code, and I tried to do this in an object:

Comment: Thanks Lawrence!
I checked the code, and I accidentally tried to do this in an object declaration:
{ name = value } instead of { name: value}
Now the interesting bit is that not even ESLint had any problem with this.

Comment: @za1234ki check if your es-lint actually lints the files.
sometimes when using eslint and tsconfig.json they interfere with each other.